# setZoom, плавный зумин

Tags: яндекс-карты

Вот кусок кода. Не весь, но для понимания будет достаточно.
Текущий зум, заданный для центра карты 10. 
Делаю myMap.panTo и на результат **.then**(function () { прописываю код ниже:

```
myMap.setZoom(14, { 
  smooth: true,
  duration: 2000
})
```

Суть проблемы - myMap.setZoom **на приближение duration НЕ работает**!
На отдаление - всё отлично.
Иногда срабатывает, но чаще нет. Мгновенное приближение, а посему, человек может не понять в каком городе точка, если точек много по России

Почему и что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У карты есть опция [`maxAnimationZoomDifference`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#Map__param-options.maxAnimationZoomDifference_modal), которая влияет для какой разницы в зумах насильно выключается анимация.

```
map.options.set('maxAnimationZoomDifference', Infinity);
map.setZoom(14, {duration: 2000}).then(() => console.log('yay'));
```

Опции `smooth` у [`setZoom`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#method_detail__setZoom) нет.

Comment: Брал из примера https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/.... там ни слова не было о том, есть или нет в ответе разработчика. Да в описании нет, видел. Просто оставил, тем боле на работу не влияет, ошибок не возвращает. Сейчас протестирую опцию.

Comment: Да, попробовал. Работает. Спасибо. Но есть особенность/вопрос. По мере приближения карта не прорисовывается, всё в мыле, потом мельтишение и центровка по месту и перерисовка... Есть ли способ прорисовки по шагам, по мере приближения?

Comment: @Sergio, такой возможности нет. Грузить тайлы, чтобы сразу же их выбросить не выгодно с точки зрения использования сети. Вы можете анимировать сами: `ymaps.vow.resolve().then(() => map.setZoom(aaa)).then(() => map.setZoom(bbb)).then(() => map.setZoom(ccc))`

Comment: Понял. Премного благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Анимация setZoom работает когда небольшая разница зума, где то не больше 4х, т.е.если ты был на зуме 10, а хочешь на 17, то не будет анимации, а если захотел на 14, то анимация будет. Чтобы пользоваться большой разницей, надо эту разницу передать через then() после срабатывания одного зума запустить следующий
к примеру
если был зум 11, то надо так

```
map.setZoom(15,{duration:200}).then(() => map.setZoom(17,{duration:200}));
```

значения зума ессно надо динамично вычислять. Другого решения увы не нашел